# Sending notifications over Firebase using cURL not working

Tags: python, firebase, curl, push-notification

I'am trying to send notifications to devices that allows notifications in a Firebase site. I have the tokens of those devices in Firebase relational database. I can successfully retrieve them, but when i send the notifications everything seems messed up.
I can send notifications using the command line method. But when i does it with a python script, its not working. Is my script right?

```
import firebase_admin
import google.cloud
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import datetime
import pycurl, json, re
now=datetime.datetime.now()
time=now.strftime("%H:%M")
print(time)
cred = credentials.Certificate("./ServiceAccountKey.json")
app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)

store = firestore.client()
doc_ref = store.collection(u'testy')
tokens=[]
try:
    docs = doc_ref.stream()
    for doc in docs:
        print(u'Doc Data:{}'.format(doc.to_dict()))
        if doc.to_dict() not in tokens:
            tokens.append(doc.to_dict())
            print('*********tokens:{}*********'.format(tokens))

except google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound:
    print(u'Missing data')
tokensnew='{}'.format(tokens)
print(tokensnew)

x=re.sub("token", "", tokensnew)
x=re.sub("]", "", x)
x=re.sub('\[', "", x)
x=re.sub("'", "", x)
x=re.sub("{", "", x)
x=re.sub("}", "", x)
x=re.sub(",", "", x)
x=re.split(" ",x)
x = list(filter(None, x))
print(x)
x=[i for i in x if i!=':']
for i in x:
    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send')
    c.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json','Authorization: key='''key goes here''''])
    print('======================{}'.format(i))
    data = json.dumps({"notification":{"title":"GTFO","body":"frame{clas},{id}.jpg" .format(clas=class_names[0],id=int(track.track_id)),"icon":"/itwonders-web-logo.png",}, "to":"{}".format(i)})
    c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, data)
    c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)
    c.perform()
    print(c.getinfo(pycurl.RESPONSE_CODE))
    certinfo = c.getinfo(pycurl.INFO_CERTINFO)
    print(certinfo)
    c.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that you tried to convert the command line curl into a verbose python script. You did a great job. But you should've mentioned the connection method. As in this script you can add `c.setopt(pycurl.POST, 1)` to the for loop that contains your pycurl statements (put it below `c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1)`).
BTW, you show look into regex more,:).